# Get pdf files from Bundle

Tags: objective-c, pdf, bundle, nsbundle

I created the Settings Bundle [image]

I done it. Because i need serf inside the bundle as the folder. For Example FileManager.
Below you can see.
[image]

And I opened meeting.Bundle in Finder using show contents and put into the Folders with pdf files. I try get these pdf files it on the device (iPhone 5) with code

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"meeting" ofType:@"bundle"];

NSString *filePathPdf = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:theFileName ofType:@"pdf"];
```

But *filePathPdf is nil. Xcode cannot find them.

[image]

What i do wrong?

PS: I found the way how to load pdf files but i think this is wrong method.
I put into meeting.bundle the folder with pdf files and put the same folder into main bundle. 
Load with path:

```
        NSString *fileNamePdf = [self.contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString* theFileName = [[fileNamePdf lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSString *filePathPdf = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theFileName ofType:@"pdf"];
```

Pdf Files loading from main bundle. But references of pdf files are taken from meeting.bundle

Maybe somebody knows how to make the right to work?

Comment: Кришнаиты уже иОС приложения заказывают? )))

Comment: @AndreyChernukha практикуем бескорыстное служение ;) Может ты знаешь ответ на мой вопрос выше ?